# Swift compiler macro / flag for String value alternative

Tags: swift

In Objective-C we could add a C Flag of `-DVAR_NAME=@\"string value\"` and then get the value with `NSString *var = VAR_NAME`.

How do we do this in Swift?

An example of this would be defining an api host based on the current git branch. Say the branch is `feature1` and it should connected to `https://feature1.example.com`. A shell script can easily find the current branch and add the C Flag. Then in Objective-C we can use the branch from the shell script to generate the api host url.

**Update**

I am not asking about boolean flags. I need to pass a string value.

**Update 2**

So far all I can come up with is to use a build script to generate a swift class.

**Update 3**

Another option is to add custom keys to the Info.plist. This isn't always an acceptable solution but for configuration values this works.

Comment: swift does not support macros

Comment: since macros aren't an option what else could we use to hard code values?

Comment: @respectTheCode Config files like any non-C languages?

Comment: Config files need to be read and that takes time. We could read the values and cache them in memory but that takes memory. None of these are blockers but they take thought. Config files work but they are not nearly as clean.

Comment: @respectTheCode clean compared to macros passed during compilation? Config files are way cleaner.

Comment: @respectTheCode `Info.plist` is cached in memory anyway. The system doesn't read it from filesystem over and over again.

Comment: @Sulthan my point was that with config files you have to manage reading and caching the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Macros are evil. They have been abused for things like this and it's not a clean solution. You have the following options (some of them already mentioned by you).

1. ***Info.plist***

The most simple, easy to read and edit. Not good for big configurations.

2. ***Your own `.plist`.***

Easy to read and edit (even from command line tools before the build, see `PlistBuddy` tool). Better for bigger configurations.

3. ***Auto generated code***

Your code can contain an expression that can be matched easily, e.g.

```
let myConfigValue = "${MY-CONFIG-VALUE}".
```

You can replace those values easily using command line tools, e.g. `sed`. This basically replicates macros without using C preprocessor. This is not very clean but usable if you already have a build system that you don't want to change.

4. ***Multiple code variants***

You can have a Swift file with configuration constants and use `#if` to switch between them.

Comment: I agree that macros have been abused. One of the great things about adopting Swift is that it is forcing everyone to revisit old code and processes.

Comment: @respectTheCode As for my recommendations, I prefer a separate plist file. Changing `Info.plist` during build time would be reflected in versioning systems so I prefer a file that can be made to be ignored by versioning. As for reading the config, it can be abstracted into a very simple class.

Answer (score 1):

Define a condition like this:

```
var window: UIWindow?

#if MYDEF
  var textureRenderThread : TextureRenderThread?
#endif
```

In the Project->Build Settings->Swift Compiler->Custom Flags

Set "-D MYDEF" as the value for "Other Swift Flags"

Comment: This only gives you a boolean value. Is the flag defined or not. Please read the question before answering.